# How can I convert micro-cents into dollars without losing decimal precision?

Tags: hive, presto

I have a column that stores transaction amounts in 'microcents'

e.g. `127740000`    microcents which corresponds to `127.74` USD

I cannot figure out how to get write a query to return 127.74 for me. If I do.

`SELECT microcents/1000000`

it truncates the return to 127 and I lose the cents

Answer (score 0):

Ugh I figured it out, CAST( blah AS DOUBLE)

Comment: Double is an approximate datatype and you generally do not want to use that for financial calculations.  Instead you should use the exact numeric DECIMAL type.

Answer (score 0):

Try DECIMAL types `select 127740000 / decimal '1000000.0000'`.  For testing, you can see the type of the output value by using the `typeof` function.